# Linux ubuntu persistent USB install E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, installation, apt-get

I created a persistent ubuntu USB install using `mkusb` but now whenever i try install any package i get the same error:

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Heres a copy of the terminal, any help would be greatly appreciated:

> elementary@elementary:~$ sudo apt-get install blender
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>           Reading state information... Done
>
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>
> blender-data fonts-dejavu libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libboost-locale1.58.0
>   libboost-regex1.58.0 libboost-thread1.58.0
>
> libdc1394-22 libgtkglext1 libjemalloc1 libopencolorio1v5
>   libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopenimageio1.6 libsdl1.2debian
>
> libspnav0 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libyaml-cpp0.3v5
>
> Suggested packages:
>
> spacenavd
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>
> blender blender-data fonts-dejavu libavdevice-ffmpeg56
>   libboost-locale1.58.0 libboost-regex1.58.0
>
> libboost-thread1.58.0 libdc1394-22 libgtkglext1 libjemalloc1
>   libopencolorio1v5 libopencv-highgui2.4v5
>
> libopenimageio1.6 libsdl1.2debian libspnav0 libtinyxml2.6.2v5
>   libyaml-cpp0.3v5
>
> 0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>
> 1 not fully installed or removed.
>
> Need to get 0 B/33.8 MB of archives.
>
> After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
>
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>
> Selecting previously unselected package blender-data.
>
> (Reading database ... 221382 files and directories currently
>   installed.)
>
> Preparing to unpack .../blender-data_2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1_all.deb ...
>
> Unpacking blender-data (2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../fonts-dejavu_2.35-1_all.deb ...
>
> Unpacking fonts-dejavu (2.35-1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libdc1394-22:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libdc1394-22_2.2.4-1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.4-1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libsdl1.2debian:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15+dfsg1-3_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg1-3) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libavdevice-ffmpeg56_7%3a2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libboost-thread1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libboost-locale1.58.0:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libboost-locale1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libboost-locale1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libjemalloc1.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libjemalloc1_3.6.0-9ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libjemalloc1 (3.6.0-9ubuntu1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libtinyxml2.6.2v5:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libtinyxml2.6.2v5_2.6.2-3_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libtinyxml2.6.2v5:amd64 (2.6.2-3) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libyaml-cpp0.3v5:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libyaml-cpp0.3v5_0.3.0-1.2_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libyaml-cpp0.3v5:amd64 (0.3.0-1.2) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libopencolorio1v5.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libopencolorio1v5_1.0.9~dfsg0-4_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libopencolorio1v5 (1.0.9~dfsg0-4) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libboost-regex1.58.0_1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libgtkglext1:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libgtkglext1_1.2.0-3.2fakesync1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libgtkglext1:amd64 (1.2.0-3.2fakesync1ubuntu1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libopencv-highgui2.4v5_2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) ...
>   Selecting previously unselected package libopenimageio1.6.
>
> Preparing to unpack
>   .../libopenimageio1.6_1.6.11~dfsg0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libopenimageio1.6 (1.6.11~dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package libspnav0.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../libspnav0_0.2.3-1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking libspnav0 (0.2.3-1) ...
>
> Selecting previously unselected package blender.
>
> Preparing to unpack .../blender_2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1_amd64.deb ...
>
> Unpacking blender (2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
>
> Processing 1 added doc-base file...
>
> Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
>
> Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils
>   (0.22-1ubuntu5.1+elementary2~ubuntu0.4.1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for bamfdaemon
>   (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
>
> Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
>
> Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
>
> Setting up cryptsetup (2:1.6.6-5ubuntu2.1) ...
>
> update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media
>
> update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported;
>   falling back to defaults
>
> insserv: Service checkroot has to be enabled to start service
>   cryptdisks-early insserv: exiting now!
>
> update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
>
> dpkg: error processing package cryptsetup (--configure):
>
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit
>   status 1
>
> Setting up blender-data (2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1) ...
>
> Setting up fonts-dejavu (2.35-1) ...
>
> Setting up libdc1394-22:amd64 (2.2.4-1) ...
>
> Setting up libsdl1.2debian:amd64 (1.2.15+dfsg1-3) ...
>
> Setting up libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
>
> Setting up libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Setting up libboost-locale1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Setting up libjemalloc1 (3.6.0-9ubuntu1) ...
>
> Setting up libtinyxml2.6.2v5:amd64 (2.6.2-3) ...
>
> Setting up libyaml-cpp0.3v5:amd64 (0.3.0-1.2) ...
>
> Setting up libopencolorio1v5 (1.0.9~dfsg0-4) ...
>
> Setting up libboost-regex1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1) ...
>
> Setting up libgtkglext1:amd64 (1.2.0-3.2fakesync1ubuntu1) ...
>
> Setting up libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) ...
>
> Setting up libopenimageio1.6 (1.6.11~dfsg0-1ubuntu1) ...
>
> Setting up libspnav0 (0.2.3-1) ...
>
> Setting up blender (2.76.b+dfsg0-3build1) ...
>
> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> cryptsetup
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
> elementary@elementary:~$

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, this is my fist post

Comment: You should better post it on askubuntu.com